# Flexbox: Using more than 2 asides

Tags: css, flexbox

this works fine so far for ONE product but what if i would like to add MORE products? Below the existing ones? Of course i could place them into the CSS also but in some cases it's not clear HOW MUCH products are display. It sure makes no sense to put dozens of aside-declarations to the CSS..

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header">Header</header>
<article class="main">
<p>Pellentesque ...</p>  
</article>
<aside class="aside aside-1">Product #1 photo</aside>
<aside class="aside aside-2">Product #1 details</aside>
<!--<aside class="aside aside-3">Product #2 photo</aside>-->
<!--<aside class="aside aside-4">Product #2 details</aside>-->
<footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;height:300px;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;height:300px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}


body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

[my code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axXpRE) (Codepen)

Comment: I don't think you are using the `aside` element the way it is supposed to be used... Also, If what you want is a series of products with its details there are other elements and css  practices you could use

Comment: ^ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside there's much more appropriate tags for what you're displaying but unless we know your use case we aren't sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbPyxp)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Product photo</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Product details</aside>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Product #2 photo</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Product #2 details</aside>
</div>
```

Put each set into divs with a row class and give the rows flex displays, border optional.

No need to do different aside classes unless you want specific colors for each product.

Ideally, you would build these products into some array that would be imported in dynamically etc but I don't know your use case.

Comment: This is a good solution; clean, and just a matter of adding a new `row` block for each item to be displayed; another solution is using grid, which won't require the wrapper row, but items still would need to be added "in pairs", as in: `.photo-element + .detail-element`